# How to create a cookie to store the timestamp of when a page is first loaded with php

Tags: php, cookies, timestamp

I would really appreciate any help if possible!

This is the question:
Use a cookie (NOT PHP SESSION) that expires a year from now to do the following:
Record the timestamp of the FIRST load of this page (but NOT any subsequent load of this page).

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>User Profile</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h3><?=$message?></h3>

     User Profile:
     <br><br>
     <form action="" method="POST" name="form1" onsubmit="return validate_form()">
      <input type="hidden" name="task" value="process_profile">

       <input type="checkbox" name="is_cool" value="yes">
       Are you cool?
       <br><br>
       What Bands do you like?
       <br>
       <select name="like_bands[]" multiple>  <small>* Required Field</small>
          <option value="Sabbath">Black Sabbath</option>
          <option value="Mastodon">Mastodon</option>
          <option value="Metallica">Metallica</option>
         <option value="Swift">Taylor Swift</option>
       </select>
       <br><br>
       Favorite band not in the above list.
       <br>
       <input type="text" name="other_band" value="">
       <br><br>
       <button type="submit"> Continue/Confirm </button>
     </form>

     <script>
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // Client-side form validation
      // Don't change the names of stuff in the form, and you won't have to change anything below
      // Used built-in JS instead of JQuery or other validation tool
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      function validate_form() {

        var form_obj = document.form1;

        var count_liked = 0;
        for (var i=0 ; i < form_obj['like_bands[]'].options.length ; i++ ) {
          if (form_obj['like_bands[]'].options[i].selected) {
            count_liked++;
          }
        }

        if (count_liked == 0) {
          alert("You must choose a band from the menu.");
          return false; // cancel form submission
        }

        return true;  // trigger form submission
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: None of the code you posted has anything to do with cookies. What part of this is confusing? Check if `$_COOKIE` contains the name you want. If not, use `setcookie()` to create it.

Comment: Yeah the page itself has no cookie. The aim is to create a cookie that stores the timestamp of when this page is first opened by a user and not anymore.

Comment: This is what I have tried so far, I am not sure if it works. `function load_dateCookie()
{
    $date = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
    $name = "load_date";
    echo $date;
    $load_date = setcookie($name, $date, time() + (86400 * 365));

    return $load_date;
}`

Comment: Put the code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: You're not checking of the cookie already exists, so you replace it every time. `if (isset($_COOKIE[$name])) { return; }`

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean. All I am supposed to do is create a cookie for the code in the question. The cookie is supposed to store the timestamp of when the page is first loaded but I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the cookie is already set. If not, set the cookie to the current timestamp.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['load_date'])) {
    setcookie('load_date', time(), time() + 86400*365);
}
```

Comment: The cookie date is not supposed to refresh. It stores the timestamp of when the page was first opened.

Comment: And that's what this should do. It doesn't refresh the cookie if it's already set.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now, thank you very much Barmar!!